# Is it valid enough to use sessions to maintain logged in user data in MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, windows-authentication

I am working on ASP.net MVC web Application. Here, in this i am implementing windows authentication. I have made necessary configurations in the `web.config` file to make it work

By using windows authentication, i was able to get the logged in user name . By using it as parameter, i am querying database to get the role for logged in user.

In my application, i have two roles. Admin and Normal User. I need to display some of the pages content based on the role of user logged in.

Can i use sessions in MVC to carry this information in every page and display the content

For example:  in Global.asax

```
               protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                 Query database....

                if( role="Admin")

                {

              Session["UserType"]="Adimn";
               }                      
             else
            {
            Session["UserType"]="NormalUser";
            }
         }
```

like this.. Then in each page, i will check this role and based on that i will hide/show some of the functionalities to the user

Is this the right approach to do this. IF not, what are the alternative ways of doing it.

Please suggest..

Answer (score 1):

You should use HttpContext.User.Identity to get current user. You can get user name and user roles:

```
var uName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
var isAdmin = HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

Answer (score 1):

As any caching approach it have positive and negative sides. Your call if you are ok with solution. Some pro/cons below.

Pros:

- less requests to DB
- faster pages (again you need to just load session state)

Cons:

- cache invalidation is complex problem: i.e. you may not know if particular user is no longer admin
- leaking session due to bugs in your site allows elevation of privileges (just need to have session ID, not need for admin credentials).